# SIGBART error - Requesting Always use location authorisation

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I'm bringing my iOS 7 app into line with the iOS8 requirements for requesting user location.

for some reason, I'm getting a sigabrt error when i call the requestalwaysAuthorisation line below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self checkLocationServicesTurnedOn];
    [self checkApplicationHasLocationServicesPermission];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
```

below is a screenshot of my info.plist:

[image: plist]

i believe i have done everything right, but its entirely possible I've missed something.

Could anybody shed some light on why I'm getting this error, and how to fix it.

Comment: What version of iOS is causing the issue? What's the full error message from the crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved the issue - i added a check as to whether the user is on iOS7 or 8, and then only applied the check if it is on iOS 8.